# How to call a function in another function in python 3.8?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, methods, self

How to call the WriteMessage function in the Start function? 
I get following Error: Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'WriteMessage' is not defined

My Code:

```
import sys,time,os

class Foo:

    def Start(self):
        message="Do something..."
        WriteMessage(message)
        name = input()
        return name

    def WriteMessage(self,message):
        for char in message:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo= Foo()
    foo= foo.Start()
```

Comment: Side note: Python has an [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Capitalizing method  names isn't very idiomatic. I suggest [changing them to `start` and `write_message`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables), as well as [moving each of your imports to separate lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). Following PEP 8 will make your code a lot easier to read for experienced Python developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you would use

```
self.WriteMessage(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've defined `WriteMessage` as a method of the class `Foo`, it isn't directly available in local or global scope. You'll need to reference an instance of the class to be able to call the function.

Had you defined `WriteMessage` as a normal function instead of a class method, you're code would work as written.

As wKavey has stated you can fix your code by adding `self.` to your function call.

```py
self.WriteMessage(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

WriteMessage is no general function, but instead a method of Foo.
Therefore, do this:

```
self.WriteMessage(message)
```